# i2cdetect -y 0 | 1 does not detect active i2c module(s)

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to verify that I2C is enabled on my Pi 3 B.

Here's what I've done  so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ uname -a
Linux rpi3b2 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

$ ls /dev
no i2c devices listed...

$ cat /etc/modules
Linux rpi3b2 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

$ cat /boot/config.txt | grep i2c
## i2c_arm
##     Enable the ARM's i2c interface
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
## i2c_vc
##     Enable the i2c interface
#dtparam=i2c_vc=on
## i2c_arm_baudrate
##     Set the baudrate of the ARM's i2c interface
#dtparam=i2c_arm_baudrate=100000
## i2c_vc_baudrate
##     Set the baudrate of the VideoCore i2c interface

$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
cmac                    2939  2
ecb                     2127  1
rfcomm                 33778  2
bnep                   10340  2
hci_uart               17943  1
btbcm                   5929  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             326105  27 bnep,btbcm,hci_uart,rfcomm
fuse                   84037  3
brcmfmac              186403  0
brcmutil                5661  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              428431  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 16037  4 cfg80211,bluetooth
bcm2835_gpiomem         3040  0
bcm2835_wdt             3225  0
uio_pdrv_genirq         3164  0
uio                     8000  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
joydev                  9024  0
evdev                  11396  4
hid_logitech_hidpp     10382  0
hid_logitech_dj        10016  0
snd_bcm2835            20447  1
snd_pcm_oss            37649  0
snd_mixer_oss          14119  1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_seq_dummy           1269  0
snd_pcm                75762  2 snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm_oss
snd_seq_oss            30670  0
snd_seq_midi            4503  0
snd_rawmidi            18516  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event      5546  2 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                53119  6 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device          3621  4 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              19288  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    51908  11 snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm_oss,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_device,snd_mixer_oss
bcm2835_v4l2           38812  0
videobuf2_vmalloc       5187  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_memops        1268  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         16535  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_core         20861  2 bcm2835_v4l2,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common             3929  2 bcm2835_v4l2,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              132913  4 bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  11573  1 videodev
-------------------------------
i2c_dev                 5859  0
-------------------------------
ipv6                  347594  58

$ i2cdetect -y 0
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-0' or `/dev/i2c/0': No such file or directory

$ i2cdetect -y 5
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-5' or `/dev/i2c/5': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Don't know why it didn't show in the listing but lsmod does show i2c_dev 5859 0.

Answer (score 1):

All the I2C entries in `/boot/config.txt` are commented out (with a # at the start of the line).

Uncomment `#dtparam=i2c_arm=on`.  I.e. change `#dtparam=i2c_arm=on` to `dtparam=i2c_arm=on` and then reboot.

Comment: Again, I thank you Joan. A comment is a commentcomment.